# How to use SAS/SQL to create a table with certain conditions from a dataset

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset with ID and event_year (event meaning something happened that year, a person has more than one record in this table with more than one event year eg. ID 1 can have three entries with event_year 2017, 2018, 2019  ). Example dataset like:

ID  event_year
1   2017
1   2018
1   2019
2   2018
2   2017

| ID | event_year |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 |
| 1 | 2018 |
| 1 | 2019 |
| 2 | 2018 |
| 2 | 2017 |

I need to get a table from this of all ID where the event_year is between 2017 and 2021 to make a frequency table counting people with event_year at set years 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021 (these are the columns refer to as study year x).

Year    frequency
2017    2
2018    2
2019    1
2020    1
2021    0

| Year | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 2017 | 2 |
| 2018 | 2 |
| 2019 | 1 |
| 2020 | 1 |
| 2021 | 0 |

Another condition is for the study year x if a person didnt have an event_year in x but had event_year x-1 they will be included in the frequency of year x, for example the ID 1 above should be included in frequency of once in each 2017, 2018, 2019 and 2020- because following the condition above for year 2020 they didnt have event_year in 2020 but did in 2019 so will be included in 2020. I apologise if this is confusing and would be happy to clarify

Comment: I suggest you to read the guidelines for posting questions, and then to edit this post. This part especially: "For questions about code, please include your code and some data to reproduce your problem, either in datalines/cards statements or using a sashelp dataset like sashelp.class or sashelp.cars."

So please include some of your data, and required end result. What you tried before also wouldn't hurt

Comment: Please follow some of the guidelines here as well [ask]

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, this should work:

```
data have;
    input ID event_year;
    datalines;
1 2017
1 2018
1 2019
2 2018
2 2017
3 2017
3 2020
;
run;
```

For the next step (your additional requirement of being included a year after last event) we need data grouped by ID.

```
proc sort data=have;
    by ID;
run;
```

We just add extra rows to a table, where a year is last year + 1.

```
data have;
    set have;
    output;
    by ID;
    if last.ID then do;
        ID=ID;
        event_year=event_year+1;
        output; 
    end;
run;
```

Now we just check how many different IDs every year had. If you want to check only for certain years, just add a where clause (for example, where event_year in (2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021) ).

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
        select distinct event_year, count(distinct ID) as frequency
            from have
            group by event_year
    ;
run;
```